# C# - Rename DataView Columns

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview

I'm working with **DataView**. I copy some columns from a datatable and insert it into DataView. Due to some requirements, I need to add some duplicate columns. But, It through the *DuplicateColumnName* Exception. Can you please help. Is there any other way to copy DataView data to DataTable?

```
stringarr = new string[] { "ML#", "Address", "Purchaser","Address","Purchaser", "Sold Price", "State", "Taxes", "Town", "Zip", "District", "Section", "Block", "Lot", "Owner" };

    DataTable distinctValues = new dataTable();
    if (cbMLSDataType.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            distinctValues = view.ToTable(false, stringarr);
        }
        else if (cbMLSDataType.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            distinctValues = view.ToTable(false, stringarr);
        }
```

Comment: Can't you just rename them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy the values of the view.

```
view.ToTable()
```

To copy the source view but not the filtered data of the DataView.

```
view.Table.Copy()
```

To copy the structure of the source DataTable.

```
view.Table.Clone()
```

Comment: Thanks. But, I need duplicate columns with the same value and names in DataView. Can you help?